# join : "File 2 not in sorted order"

Tags: sort, join

I've got two files _jeter3.txt and _jeter1.txt

I've checked they are both sorted on the 20th column using `sort -c`

```
sort -t '     ' -c -k20,20 _jeter3.txt
sort -t '     ' -c -k20,20 _jeter1.txt
#no errors
```

but there is an error when I want to `join` both files it says that the second file is not sorted:

```
join -t '   ' -1 20 -2 20 _jeter1.txt _jeter3.txt > /dev/null
join: File 2 is not in sorted order
```

I don't understand why.

```
cat /etc/*-release #FYI
openSUSE 11.0 (i586)
VERSION = 11.0
```

**UPDATE**:  using '`sort -f`'  and `join -i` (both case insensitive) fixes the problem. But it doesn't explain my initial problem.

**UPDATE**: versions of sort & join:

```
> join --version
join (GNU coreutils) 6.11
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
(...)

> sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 6.11
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
(...)
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of "join --version" and "sort --version"  just for completeness sake?  I can't get some older versions of gnu join to give me that error message under any circumstance.

Comment: Please post some sample data that exhibits the problem, and the output of `locale`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got the same error with Ubuntu 11.04, with `sort` and `join` both in version (GNU coreutils) 8.5.

They are clearly incompatible.  In fact the `sort` command seems bugged: there is no difference with or without the `-f` (`--ignore-case`) option. When sorting, `aaB` is always before `aBa`. Non alphanumeric characters seems also always ignored (`abc` is before `ab-x`)

Join seems to expect the opposite... But I have a solution

In fact, this is linked to the collation sequence: using `LANG=en_EN sort -k 1,1 <myfile> ...` then `LANG=en_EN join ...` eliminates the message.

Internationalisation is the root of evil... (nobody documents it clearly).

Comment: So, if both use `LANG=en_EN`, then it will definitely work? Will it work for any locale, as long as both use the same locale? Can we say that the difference between `sort` and `join` is that they use a different locale by default?

Comment: Is the `-k` option the answer here, or is it the `LANG=en_EN`? It's unclear of what the exact solution is here.

Comment: LANG=en_EN is the solution

Answer (score 8):

`sort` by default uses the entire line as the key

`join` uses only the specified field as the key.

You must correct this incompatibility by restricting sort to use only the key you want to join on.

The Join man page states:

> Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields. E.g., use 'sort -k 1b,1' if >'join' has no options. Note, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'. If the >input is not sorted and some lines cannot be joined, a warning message will be given.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. Sorting by a full line doesn't produce the partial line in the wrong order such that join should complain about it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure you properly sorted your input files and their lines can be paired, you can avoid the above error by running `join --nocheck-order file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: The error is not reported, but the result is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you see this error, and you have already sorted on a specific column and are beating your head against the wall e.g. sort -k4,4 then you may also need to set the separator for the sort command

Apparently OP already did this with -t '      ' but for a normal tab separated text I'd recommend

```
sort -t $'\t' ...
```

The sort command can incorporate spaces as separators by default even on something that looks like a tab separated file (especially if there are spaces inside the column you are sorting on).

Then if you passed that sorted data to join, and you have

```
join -t $'\t' ...
```

Then this ends up causing the error message about it being unsorted. As noted above, join may not accept -t '      ' though.

Answer (score 5):

Were you sorting with numbers? I found that zero-padding the column that I was joining on solved this issue for me.

```sh
cat file.txt \
     | awk -F"   " '{ $20=sprintf("%06s", $20); print $0}' \
     | sort > readytojoin.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
LOCALE=C sort ...
LOCALE=C join ...
```

This will solve your problem. The issue, as pointed out by @Michael, is collation sequence, which depends on your LOCALE setting.

Answer (score 0):

For join the argument after -t is a character. For sort you can supply a longer sort separator. I think that you may be joining the files on a different field that you want to, and ignoring the case solves the problem by coincidence.

And I agreee with Gilles, that sample data would be helpful.