# sort not working for similar entries

Tags: sort

I am sorting a file prior to joining it with another file, using

```
sort -k1 file1 > file1_sort
```

When I try to join with the second file, I get an error saying file1 is not sorted. I think this is occurring because of the following entry:

```
chr6_32609371_I I2 D 
chr6_32609371 T C
```

The "chr6_32609371" line needs to be placed before the "chr6_32609371_I" in my sorted file. Is there an argument I can add to the sort command to get this to happen?

Comment: `sort -k1,1` to sort on the first column. `-b` may also be needed.

Comment: Check that your `sort` invocations have the same locale. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/join-file-2-not-in-sorted-order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `sort -k1` will not sort according to the first field but *from* the first field to the end of the line. From `man sort` (emphasis mine):

> KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
>   where    F is a field number and C a character position in the field; 
>   both  are    origin 1, and **the stop position defaults to the line's
>   end.**

So, `-k1` is comparing `chr6_32609371_I I2 D` to `chr6_32609371 T C` and since `I` is before `T`, it is sorting as you see. To get around this, you should tell `sort` to only take into account the 1st field by passing both a start and an end position:

```
sort -k1,1 file
```