# specific case where sort and join are not working

Tags: sort, join

I have an issue joining the two files linked below using `join -t $'\t' -a1 file_1 file_2`. I'm aware that one has to use specific flags when sorting in order to make join work, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431673/linux-join-utility-complains-about-input-file-not-being-sorted/25432076#25432076) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/join-file-2-not-in-sorted-order) post. Specifically, I have sorted both file_1 and file_2 using the following syntax: `cat file_1 | LANG=en_EN sort k1b,1`.

The error I get is this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vlh9NqD1Nlm6dQi33Qt0gevsLfYxRURN

This is problematic. For example, entry "S2_005_008G1__bin.1" fails to be joined despite being present in both file_1 and file_2.

Sorry that I cannot give a simple toy example, but I've been unable to regenerate this error using hand-made files. I really at a loss as what might cause this issue.

[file_1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15YHosMHc2nIer-vyAjhAfYFEtbbWAfZu), [file_2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1Jv_IUXDM5klpYhGZXrSY1fxC7xEQQ3)

Comment: This is a bad question because you didn't copy the actual commands that you ran (for example you obviously ran `sort -k1b,1`, not `sort k1b,1`) or the error messages. Always copy-paste, never copy things manually or post a screenshot of text. I answered the question because I can probably guess what you did wrong and it might help others, but don't expect this to happen often when you don't even bother to copy-paste your code and data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use matching options and locale settings for `join` and `sort`. If you tell `join` to use tab-separated fields, you also need to tell `sort` to use tab-separated fields (the default is whitespace-separated).

Setting the `LANG` environment variable may or may not set the `LC_COLLATE` locale setting: if the environment `LC_COLLATE` is set, it takes precedence over `LANG`, and if the environment variable `LC_ALL` is set, it sets all locale settings. See [set LC_* but not LC_ALL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all/15334#15334)

Unless you need to have the files sorted in a particular “human-friendly” way, use the `C` collation locale, which simply uses byte order. And unless you need some other locale setting to be different, set `LC_ALL` to be sure to override any setting inherited from the rest of the script or from a parent process. In any case, make sure to use the same locale settings for `join` and `sort`.

```
LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\t' -k 1b,1 file_1 >file_1.sorted
LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\t' -k 1b,1 file_2 >file_2.sorted
LC_ALL=C join -t $'\t' -a1 file_1.sorted file_2.sorted
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! How come the join/sort statement doesn't work without setting LC_all=C? Shouldn't this be set to the same value by default when invoking join/sort?