# Joining two sorted files gives error: join: <file>:112855: is not sorted:

Tags: linux, sort, join

I would like to merge a variable from one file to another in linux.
The first variable contains the name I want to merge files on.

I have sorted both files using both -f and -k:
`sort -f -k 1,1 SCZ.N.tmp> SCZ.N.tmp.sorted` and `sort -f -k 1,1 1kg.tmp > 1kG.ref_file.sorted`

However, when I join both files with this command: `join -1 1 -2 1 SCZ.N.tmp.sorted 1kG.ref_file.sorted> SCZ.freq.joined`

I keep getting the error '*join: SCZ.N.tmp.sorted:112855: is not sorted: chr1_100002155_D D I6 0.995112 0.0184 0.7897 87016*' Nevertheless, the join continues and the majority is merged. However, I am not sure whether I am losing a small proportion of cases because of mismatch between the files, or because something goes wrong with sorting these files.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? And what i can do to not get this error?
Thank you!

I have also tried: `LANG=en_EN sort -f -k 1,1 SCZ.N.tmp> SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2` and `LANG=en_EN sort -f -k 1,1 1kg.tmp > 1kg.tmp.sorted2`, with then joining using: `LANG=en_EN join -1 1 -2 1 SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2 1kg.tmp.sorted2> SCZ.freq.joined`. But that did not solve it.

Comment: I would try `LC_COLLATE=en_EN`. I suspect LANG only affects presentation, not sequencing. Failing that, try `LC_ALL=C` which is the ultimate sanction.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both `LC_COLLATE=en_EN` and `LC_ALL=C` which made the error change to _join: SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2:317251: is not sorted: MERGED_DEL_2_4660 D I5 0.98738 0.0113 0.2611 87016_ but comes down the same final joined sample size...

Comment: It complained about the second file now. Did you change all three instances of the LANG to LC_ALL=C? This export only applies to the command that follows directly on the same line with no intervening semi-colon.

Comment: Yes I did apply it to all 3. I just tried `LOCALE=C` and that gave the earlier error again with  _join: SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2:112855: is not sorted:_

Comment: Sorry, LC_ALL has always worked for me. I suspect the things in the messages like 112855 and 317251 are line numbers in the sorted files, so you could look at sections of the files to see if there are crazy characters. LOCALE is not meaningful: run the `locale` command to see valid names and current settings. Run `LC_ALL=C locale` to see what it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting the files with the -f option, as case-independent keys.

However, join expects the keys in normal sorted sequence.

You should add the -i option to the command-line for join, to have it ignore case differences.

Alternatively, omit the -f option from both sorts.

Edit: also found another possibility [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581248/specific-case-where-sort-and-join-are-not-working?rq=1). The field separators need to be identical for the sort and the join. It looks like the defaults for sort and join are both whitespace, but it may be the next hurdle.

Comment: This has solved my problem, thank you a lot! So in the end I have now used:
 `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1 SCZ.N.tmp> SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2` and   `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1 1kg.tmp > 1kg.tmp.sorted2` and then `LC_ALL=C join -1 1 -2 1 SCZ.N.tmp.sorted2  1kg.tmp.sorted2 > SCZ.freq.joined2`. Thanks again!